# pandas calculating distance based on LatLong values on 2 separate rows

Tags: python, pandas, latitude-longitude

I have a dataframe like this:

```
[{ "user" : "sgeth",
   "Lat" : "50.7207",
   "Long" : "-1.87566"},
 { "user" : "sgeth",
   "Lat" : "50.7206",
   "Long" : "-1.87579"}]
```

There are more elements, but for the sake of time I have omitted them. If I have grouped this dataframe by user so I could apply a function by group. My question is how would I access the group element's coordinates and the element after it?

Comment: How many element (row) do you have per group?

Comment: @rpanai They are different lengths. It varies between 2 - 162

Comment: You can also try Indexing by user. like this df[df['user']=="sgeth"]

Comment: Not sure I get the idea. You have two users here, with one paid of Lat and Long for each. What distances are you trying to calculate?

Comment: @Roy2012 good point thanks for pointing it out. Fixed the question, but to answer your question, I'm trying to retrieve the 4 latitude and longitude so I can plug it into a function that takes in 2 sets of coordinates and returns the distance between them.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, `df.groupby('user')[['Lat', 'Long']].apply(some_func)`?

Comment: @r.ook exactly that